# Jekyll - syntax for a for loop in range given by two integer variables

Tags: arrays, jekyll, liquid

In Python, what I would like to achieve is:

```
count = 0
for i in range(count, count+5):
    count
```

What is the syntax for this with Jekyll, if it is possible?

```
{% assign count = 0 %}
{% for i in (...) %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define range with integers `{% for i in (1..10) %}` or with variables `{% for i in (myVar..myOtherVar) %}`